# Is Shaytan an Angel or Jinn?

Tags: jinn, malaikah, shaitan

I have heard that Shaytan is an Angel but then Angels do not have free will so this means he has to obey Allah, but he did have free will because he did not prostrate to Adam (عليه السلام) when Allah commanded him to do so.

Quran [2:34](http://quran.com/2/34):

> And (remember) when We said to the angels: "Prostrate yourselves
>   before Adam." And they prostrated except Iblis (Satan), he refused and
>   was proud and was one of the disbelievers (disobedient to Allah)"

I have also heard that he is a jinn.

Quran [18:50](http://quran.com/18/50):

> And (remember) when We said to the angels; "Prostrate to Adam." So
>   they prostrated except Iblis (Satan). He was one of the jinns; he
>   disobeyed the Command of his Lord.

Comment: I urge you to select the accepted answer from those who actually answered all of your concerns and not by the # of votes it has.

Comment: Especially some statements in the tafsir of Imam at-Tabari may create a confusion for Iblis being an Angel or a Jinn, but else the Quran is crystal clear when defining Angels, Jinn and Humans.

Answer (score 2):

ٍٍِSatan/Shaytan is a jinn and never been an angel and the evidence is in how Satan was created. Satan is created from fire and therefore it's a jinn. Whereas the angels are created from light.

When Allah asked angels and him *"Prostrate yourselves before Adam"*. Satan refused to do so and in turn said *"You create me from **fire** and I will not prostrate to one who created from mud"*.

Comment: Yes I know why he didnt prostrate but why does the Qur'an say all angels except Iblis which means Iblis too is an angel?

Comment: "all angels except Iblis" doesn't necessarily imply that the Iblis is an angel. AFAIK English.

Comment: -1 for not answering the OP's concern about the second verse.

Answer (score 2):

Iblis is from the jin.  Shayateen are also from the jinn.  Allah tells us in Surah al-Hijr [15:27](http://quran.com/15/27)

> And the jinn We created before from scorching fire.

In Surah Saad, Allaah tells us what Iblis said:

> He said, "I am better than him. You created me from fire and created
>   him from clay."

In Surah al-Baqara [2:34](http://quran.com/2/34), Allah says:

> And when We said to the angels, "Prostrate before Adam"; so they
>   prostrated, except for Iblis. He refused and was arrogant and became
>   of the disbelievers.

And in Surah an-Nahl [16:49](http://quran.com/16/49):

> And to Allah prostrates whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on
>   the earth of creatures, and the angels, and they are not arrogant.

So in these verses, Allah tells us what He created jinn from.  Iblis said he was made from it. And Allah tells us angels don't have kibr and Iblis was Mutakabir (arrogant).

Iblis is from the jinn and had kibr.

Comment: So based on the Ayah you posted he is from the Angels? I don't think your answer is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Satan was a hybrid Angel-Jinn. It is said that he was made from fire but it is also said that his light was brighter than all the other angels. It means that he must be an angel as well. And we all know how hybrids are usually stronger than their pure raced parents in nature. Thus it explains the Satan's power.

Comment: The only answer deserving of a +1 from all the other answers and the only answer that actually addresses all of the OPs concerns.

Answer (score 0):

When Allah says that he told the angels to prostrate, and they prostrated, except Iblis, he means that Iblis was among the ranks of the angels. An angel obeys God's every command, but as we can see, Iblis didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Satan is a Jinn. people that say he was an angel base it on when Allah says,
"Prostrate yourselves before Adam." And they prostrated except Iblis (Satan), he refused and was proud and was one of the disbelievers (disobedient to Allah)
basically they are saying he was included when Allah called the angels.
to simplify it think about it like this. you have a fifth grader that is really smart so he is bumped up to sixth grade. the teacher wont call him a fifth grader.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is, Iblish actually was a very devoted jinn before turning into iblish/satan! Who always worshipped Allah and for that Allah made him an Angel as a reward. But at the same time iblish was jealous, arrogant so when Allah told him about Adam, iblish said O Allah why do you want to create new creatures? Aren't we Angels enough for you? If you create humans they will disobey You, fight and kill one another like jinns!

When Allah created Adam and said to all the Angels, "Prostrate yourselves before Adam", everybody prostrated except iblish! His heart was filled with too much pride so he refused and said "You create me from fire and I will not prostrate to one who created from mud"

*****Jinns are created from fire
*****Angels are created from light

Answer (score 0):

“And (remember) when We said to the angels: “Prostrate yourselves unto Adam.” So they prostrated themselves except Iblis (Satan). He was one of the jinn; he disobeyed the command of his Lord. Will you then take him (Iblis) and his offspring as protectors and helpers rather than Me while they are enemies to you? What an evil is the exchange for the Zalimoon (polytheists, and wrongdoers, etc).” [18:50]

2. Allah stated that He created the jinn from fire, as He says (interpretation of the meaning):

“And the jinn, We created aforetime from the smokeless flame of fire” [15:27]

“And the jinn He created from a smokeless flame of fire” [55:15]

Answer (score 0):

its a translation issue, in arabic, there is a law of taqlib, this means that if the majority is addressed, the minority need not be addressed, shaytaan was among the Angels but was not one of them, Allah (SWT) addressed the angels, but shaytaan was among them, 1 jinn, so Allah did not have to say angels and 1 jinn, Allah just said angels, the law of Taqlib applied
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Cx3EVgbhO8

Comment: you cant just read the Quran translation and try to understand it, there are rules in the arabic grammar that has to be acknowledged, Allah does not need to singularly address shaytaan, Allah just needed to address the majority, automatically shaytaan is included but not addressed

Comment: you can mark down these points, I didnt sign up for that and probably wont be on here again, just wanted to help

Answer (score -1):

Shaytan is a jinn, the specific verse you have here:

> And (remember) when We said to the angels: "Prostrate yourselves before Adam." And they prostrated except Iblis (Satan), he refused and was proud and was one of the disbelievers (disobedient to Allah)

doesn't mean that he is an angel. To clarify this I'm going to give this example:

You have 99 persons from the grade 5 and 1 person from grade 6, then the logic is that you will call them 5th graders even if you meant to add the one from 6 grade with them.

Comment: Invalid logic. You will not call them 5th graders unless they all are indeed 5th graders. That 1 there doesn't make that true, unless you are saying Allah subhana watala makes mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

Ibles is from djinn also called shaytan there are many, a lot of shayateen not one.

in the west, it is a confused Idea.  even devils, demons are bad news, but from djinn they are known as sofly. Djinn Rahmani are those on the path of Allah. a number of them took on themselves to protect Bano Adam from the deeds of the evil one

like what the brother said they can only tell you to do evil they can not make you.  you have free will.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider adding evidences to support your claims (see [answer]).

Answer (score -2):

I think untill now Azazel/Iblish was a jinn because he was created from fire, he had free will, he disobeyed, he was proudy etc.

Answer (score -2):

Shaytan had the status of an angel. He wasnt an angel. He was a jin as jins are made out of fire.

Comment: Can you add your reference into answer?

Answer (score -2):

He was a jiin and it shouldn't worry you becoz his powerless he disobeyed Allah because he thought he was gonna be more by being created from fire but he never gave a thought that Allah has attributes and he doesn't I hope that helps ..